# MySql query to get all combinations of two columns with NULL if there is no matching record

Tags: mysql, null, combinations

I have a Table which has the records of the down time of a server.
I have created a simplified version of this table at sqlfiddle. Please see here [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8479e/8)

The table has each record like

```
Reason  Month   Down_Time
A       May     2
A       May     5
B       May     5
C       July    15
A       July    3
B       June    6
A       June    8
C       June    2
```

I need to write a query to get all combinations of give Month and Reason with NULL if there is no matching record
As an example : If I need to get the down time of the system in May, June and July due to Reason A,B or D.. What I am expecting is..

```
Reason  Month   DOWNTIME
A       May     7
A       June    8
A       July    3
B       May     5
B       June    6
B       July    NULL
D       May     NULL
D       June    NULL
D       July    NULL
```

Since we don't have D in the records for given months, it should be NULL

This is my Query:

```
 SELECT Reasons.reason, Months.Month,sum( a.Down_time ) AS downtime
 FROM tabledown a
 RIGHT JOIN (
 SELECT 'A' AS reason
 UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS reason
 UNION ALL SELECT 'D' AS reason
 ) Reasons
  ON a.reason = Reasons.reason
 RIGHT JOIN (
 SELECT 'May' AS month
  UNION ALL SELECT 'June' AS month
  UNION ALL SELECT 'July' AS month
 ) Months
 ON a.Month = Months.month
 GROUP BY Reasons.reason,Months.month
 ORDER BY Reasons.reason
```

Why i am not getting the expected output :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Your first outer join](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8479e/19/0), as expected, produces:

```
| REASON |  MONTH |
-------------------
|      A |    May |
|      A |    May |
|      A |   July |
|      A |   June |
|      B |    May |
|      B |   June |
|      D | (null) |
```

However, because outer joins produce results if the join condition is satisfied *at least once* (and only introduce `NULL` records if the condition is *never* satisfied), [your second outer join](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8479e/20/0) then *does not* produce a record for `(B, July)`; it also drops `Reason = 'D'` entirely, because the join condition is not met (and all three months have been satisfied elsewhere):

```
| REASON | MONTH |
------------------
|      A |   May |
|      A |   May |
|      B |   May |
|      A |  June |
|      B |  June |
|      A |  July |
```

Whilst you *could* resolve the loss of `Reason = 'D'` [by adding](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8479e/21/0) `OR a.Month IS NULL` to your join condition, you still will not produce `(B, July)`.  Instead, because you want to obtain every pair of `(Reason, Month)`, you must `CROSS JOIN` your materialised `Reasons` table with your materialised `Months` table:

```
SELECT Reason, Month
FROM   
  (
    SELECT 'A' AS Reason
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'D'
  ) Reasons CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'May' AS Month
    UNION ALL SELECT 'June'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'July'
  ) Months
```

```
| REASON | MONTH |
------------------
|      A |   May |
|      B |   May |
|      D |   May |
|      A |  June |
|      B |  June |
|      D |  June |
|      A |  July |
|      B |  July |
|      D |  July |
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8479e/1/0).

You then merely need outer join the result with your underlying data:

```
SELECT Reason, Month, SUM(Down_time) downtime
FROM   
  (
    SELECT 'A' AS Reason
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'D'
  ) Reasons CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'May' AS Month
    UNION ALL SELECT 'June'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'July'
  ) Months
  LEFT JOIN tabledown USING (Reason, Month)
GROUP BY Reason, Month
```

```
| REASON | MONTH | DOWNTIME |
-----------------------------
|      A |  July |        3 |
|      A |  June |        8 |
|      A |   May |        7 |
|      B |  July |   (null) |
|      B |  June |        6 |
|      B |   May |        5 |
|      D |  July |   (null) |
|      D |  June |   (null) |
|      D |   May |   (null) |
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8479e/2/0).

Comment: Thanks @eggyal ! You Are GENIUS! and a great teacher.This works perfectly.. Thanks again for your detailed explanation