# Mysql - 0 count if no rows of

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a query to count the number of entries of different categories of different states. I have grouped the rows of a table first by category, and then by state. This is a version of my current query:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'A_1',
            'A_2'
        ) THEN 'Category A'
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'B_1',
            'B_2'
        ) THEN 'Category B'
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'C_1',
            'C_2'
        ) THEN 'Category C'
    ELSE 'Other'/*This should not happen, if it does, something is wrong.*/
    END AS CATEGORY,
    J.STATUS,
    COUNT(*) AS STATUS_COUNT
FROM JOB J
WHERE J.FINISHED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND (
    DAYNAME(J.FINISHED_TIME) = 'Saturday'
    OR DAYNAME(J.FINISHED_TIME) = 'Sunday')
AND J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
    /*All relevant categories*/
   'A_1',
   'A_2',
   'B_1',
   'B_2',
   'C_1',
   'C_2'
)
GROUP BY
    CASE
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'A_1',
            'A_2'
        ) THEN 'Category A'
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'B_1',
            'B_2'
        ) THEN 'Category B'
    WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN (
            'C_1',
            'C_2'
        ) THEN 'Category C'
    ELSE 'Other'/*This should not happen, if it does, something is wrong.*/
    END,
    J.STATUS
```

The result of the query currently looks like this:

```
CATEGORY   | STATUS   | COUNT

Category A   Success    117

Category A   Failure    19

Category B   Success    208
```

When I need the results to look like this:

```
CATEGORY   | STATUS   | COUNT

Category A   Success    117

Category A   Failure    19

Category B   Success    208

Category B   Failure    0

Category C   Success    0

Category C   Failure    0
```

How can I modify my query in order to return empty rows in that way so all categories will be visible in the result set with 0s if there were no rows?

Comment: If you have no records, then there is no row.  you would need to generate a set of data consisting of distinct J.Misc_Category_Config, and J.Status and then left join to your job table to get all records including those with no value.  Put another way, since your where clause limits by past 7 days, there have been no category c success or failure jobs on sat/Sun with time > now.  To get them to show, you need to get distinct category and status independent of date

Comment: Tip of today: Wrap your select with case up in a derived table. GROUP BY its result. Will save some typing and is much less error prone.

Comment: This answer will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668285/2225030

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:
We create a set of data containing the relevant categories/statuses we care about (I called it AllCatStat)  we left join this to your base set of data in jobs which allows us to group by and get the count of relevant status records in the left joined table.  which will be 0 records to x records.

```
SELECT AllCatStat.Category
     , AllCatStat.Status
     , count(J.Status) as COUNT
/*Get Distinct category and status for all jobs having a misc_Category_Config we care about*/

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('A_1','A_2') THEN 'Category A'
                           WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('B_1','B_2') THEN 'Category B'
                           WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('C_1','C_2') THEN 'Category C' 
                           ELSE 'Other' End as Category,
                           J.Status
      FROM JOB
      WHERE MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('A_1', 'A_2', 'B_1', 'B_2','C_1','C_2'))  AllCatStat

/*Get List of Jobs Meeting our criteria and format to desired category*/
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('A_1','A_2') THEN 'Category A'
                       WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('B_1','B_2') THEN 'Category B'
                       WHEN J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('C_1','C_2') THEN 'Category C'
                       ELSE 'Other' /*This should not happen, if it does, something is wrong.*/
                       END AS CATEGORY,
                  J.STATUS
           FROM JOB J
           WHERE J.FINISHED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
             AND (DAYNAME(J.FINISHED_TIME) = 'Saturday'
               OR DAYNAME(J.FINISHED_TIME) = 'Sunday')
             AND J.MISC_CATEGORY_CONFIG IN ('A_1',   'A_2',   'B_1',   'B_2',   'C_1',   'C_2')
          ) J
 ON AllCatStat.Category = J.Category
and AllCatStat.Status = J.Status

GROUP BY AllCatStat.CATEGORY
       , AllCatStat.STATUS
```